# Where can I check Google API Key after I got it?

Tags: android

I have created a Google android API key.
But how do I check my generated api key in my application.

Comment: It seems to me if I was going to generate a key for something I'd know why I needed it and how to use it *before* I generated it.

Answer (score 0):

console.developers.google.com to see the api key google provides.  You place this key in your application's class that makes the api calls.

Comment: k i got key for my app but after got key where have to i seach that key within my app if i didn't save no my manifest file

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse, go to Edit-->Find.  In android studio, go to Edit-->Find-->Find in Path and search for the key the developer console shows to see where you put it in your project.